# Power BI Miltidimensional model support

Tags: powerbi, azure-analysis-services

*Does Power BI support AAS (SSAS) MD?*

My confusion comes from [this article](https://www.element61.be/en/resource/choice-between-tabular-or-multidimensional-models-sql-server-analysis-services-2012). See "Table 2: Pros and Cons Tabular Model vs. Multidimensional Model". There said that multidimensional model can't be used with Pwer View.

In other hand, [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-ssas-multidimensional) has list of PBI + SSAS MD cababilities.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cloud service Azure Analysis Services is Tabular only, it does not support the Multi Dimensional type. 
Power BI can connect to and use SSAS MD (and SSAS Tabular), but these instances will be on premise, or on a VM in Azure.

Hope that helps